# Lightning component not returning a response

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, response

I Have a lightning component from which I pass data to an apex class. I return the object. Why don't I get an update on my object neither a response in my lightning component.

Lightning

```
updatePicklist : function(component,event,helper){ 
    var selectedValues = $('[id$=picklist]').select2("val");
    var field = component.get("v.fieldName");
    var object = component.get("v.objectName");
    var getCurrentRecord = component.get("v.recordId"); 
    var action = component.get("c.updateRecord");
    action.setParams({
        "objId": getCurrentRecord,
        "objNew": object,
        "selection" : selectedValues,
        "fieldName" : field
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {
            alert('record Updated Successfully-->' + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));   
            //Fire the refresh view event to update detail view
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static sObject updateRecord(string objNew, id objId , string selection, string fieldName){
    sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objNew).newSObject(objId) ;
    sObj.put(fieldName , selection) ;
    update sObj ;
    return sObj;
}

Logging
16:22:13.0 (161658)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Aura
16:22:13.0 (1468788)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p1l0000008UC9|select2TestCtrl.updateRecord(String, Id, String, String)
16:22:13.0 (1708031)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
16:22:13.0 (1828648)|USER_DEBUG|[19]|DEBUG|null null null null
16:22:13.0 (14355318)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.select2TestCtrl.updateRecord: line 20, column 1
16:22:13.0 (14381632)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.select2TestCtrl.updateRecord: line 20, column 1
16:22:13.0 (14398622)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|select2TestCtrl.updateRecord(String, Id, String, String)
16:22:13.0 (18207207)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Aura
16:22:13.0 (19271021)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: mind further elaborating on ' I don't get an update on my object neither a response ' ? your refresh event is fired? is your apex method invoked?  is your alert fired? even if it were, and your apex method invoked, the refresh wont guarantee an updated view of the record since the action enters a queue and the update can take place after you refresh your view

Comment: Can you turn on logging and see if there is an error on the server? Also wrap your javascript function with a try/catch. Sometimes lightning won't display syntax errors in the console

Comment: @Programatic I turned on logging, good idea. but cant figure out why my debug returns null see my update

Comment: @glls My apex method is invoked, my alert is not fired, id updated the thread with some logging

Comment: did you debug the "response.getState()"? Is it  "SUCCESS"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the apex class the selection is defined as string, this should be list

```
public static sObject updateRecord(string objNew, id objId , string selection, string fieldName)
```

must be

```
public static sObject updateRecord(string objNew, id objId , List<string> selection, string fieldName)
```

Then convert list to string like this

```
string picklistsel = '';
        for(string sel : selection){
            picklistsel += sel +';';
        }
sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objNew).newSObject(objId) ;
        sObj.put(fieldName , picklistsel) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why don't I get an update on my object ?

-> null null null null

Cant get create a record if your apex controlLer does not receive any values.

> Why dont I get a response in my lightning component?

Your response.getState() is NOT Success.

you aren't handling anything other than success, which is in part why you dont get feedback in your lightning controller.

If you check [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm), you'll notice that there arer other response states being handled in order to know what is going on in your controller such as INCOMPLETE or ERROR

```
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
```

As a best practice, you might want to incldue those in your code for future reference.

In production - You will  most likely want to display a toast message for when a server response fails, in order to notify the user.

The [lightning:notificationsLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation) can provide the neccessary support for doing so:
you will need to include:

```
<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
```

in your component markup to be able to display a Toast, and in your state validation logic invoke  the action to display it alongside your error message:

```
 component.find('notifLib').showToast({
        "title": "Notif library Success!",
        "message": "The record has been updated successfully."
    });
```

Comment: I added this with some alerts. I get an alert on an incomplete state so I still dont have a clue

Comment: well, the reason you werent getting a response, was because of the lack of error handling, why the object was not created, because of the NullPointerException. I would recommend opening a new post if you are unsure why the NullPointerException occurs and how to pass the parameters to your apex controller.

Comment: Best practice would certainly not be `console.log` though, it would be to fire a toast message event.

Answer (score 0):

Also the apex class should have a try catch so the error is handled correctly in your lightning helper as glls mentioned. Something like 
catch(exception e)
    throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());